How does AWS auto scaling decide on scaling-in?
I have a question regarding autoscaling in AWS, scaling-in to be specific.
What I want to understand is that when auto-scaling-group decides to scale-in (ie remove ec2 instance/s), how does it decide which one to remove? An instance may be performing some task. How does ASG knows of that?

If you are worried about an instance currently processing a task, you can use Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling lifecycle hooks - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling which provide an opportunity for tasks to be completed before the instance is terminated.

First it checks if your application has more EC2 instances in a one availability zone than your other availability zones, and deletes an instance from that zone. It tries to delete the oldest instance in that availability zone.
That is the default behavior, but you can also configure it to behave differently. This is all documented in Control which Auto Scaling instances terminate during scale in - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling.
